# Nested Ordered List Numbering Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm making a Table of Contents with nested numeric ordered lists.  It starts off well, but once I go back a level the numbering gets off.  As you can see once it gets to the 4th level not only is the numbering off, but now everything has one extra number, regardless of level.

This is what I end up with:

```
SECTION 1
1 Item 1
    1.1 Sub Item
        1.1.1 Level 3 Item
            1.1.1.1 Level 4 Item
            1.1.1.2 Level 4 Item
            1.1.1.3 Level 4 Item
            1.1.1.4 Level 4 Item
            1.1.1.5 Level 4 Item
        1.1.1.6 Level 3 Item
            1.1.1.1 Level 4 Item
        1.1.1.2 Level 3 Item
        1.1.1.3 Level 3 Item
    1.1.2 Level 2 Item
```

This is the code I'm using:

```css
    ol.toc {
      counter-reset: item;
    }
    
    li.toc {
      display: block;
    }
    
    li.toc:before {
      content: counters(item, ".") " ";
      counter-increment: item;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table of Contents</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div style="float: clear;">
    <ol class="toc">
      <li class="toc">&nbsp; Item 1</li>
      <ol class="toc">
        <li class="toc">&nbsp; Sub Item</li>
        <ol class="toc">
          <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
          <ol class="toc">
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
          </ol>
          <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
          <ol class="toc">
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
          </ol>
          <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
          <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
        </ol>
        <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 2</li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Not sure what's going on.  I haven't found too many examples that fit my needs.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the wrong numbering is happening because you should wrap every child `<ol>` in it's parent `<li>`. And for better look set `list-style-type:none;` of the top most parent `<ol>`.

Check it out:

```css
ol.toc {
  counter-reset: item;
}

li.toc {
  display: block;
}

li.toc:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}

.outer li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Table of Contents</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>SECTION 1</h2>
  </div>

  <div style="float: clear;">
    <ol class="toc outer">
      <li class="toc">&nbsp; Item 1</li>
      <ol class="toc">
        <li class="toc">&nbsp; Sub Item</li>
        <li>
          <ol class="toc">
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
            <li>
              <ol class="toc">
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
            <li>
              <ol class="toc">
                <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 4 Item</li>
              </ol>
            </li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
            <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 3 Item</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="toc">&nbsp; Level 2</li>
      </ol>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```